# Implementation for Implicit social signup in spring-boot project

Tags: spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, spring-social-twitter

By adding the spring-social signin / signup to my current spring-boot project, through the implementation of the classes `ConnectionSignUp` and `SignInAdapter`, the application, after the authorization with the social network website, it's requiring the implementation of a mapping for "/signup" in my controller. In this method, I do basically the same what I already have implemented on the ConectionSignUp method. Anyone knows what I can do to avoid this duplicity, and direct the application to my `ConnectionSignUp` class instead of one extra method on my controller?

my implementation so far includes the following classes:

**ConnectionSIgnUp**

```
@Component
public class CustomConnectionSignUp implements ConnectionSignUp {
  @Autowired
  private UsuarioDao account;

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender mailSender;

  public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
    UserProfile profile = connection.fetchUserProfile();

    String user;
    try {
      Usuario novo = new Usuario(profile.getUsername(),UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", ""),null,null,false,true);
      account.insert(novo);
      return novo.getLogin();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**SignInAdapter**

```
@Component
public class CustomSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private SocialUserDetailsService socialUserDetailsService;

  public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
    SocialUserDetails user = socialUserDetailsService.loadUserByUserId(userId);
    if(user != null)
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUserId(), null, null));
    return null;
  }
}
```

**SocialUserDetailsService**

```
@Service

    public class CustomSocialUserDetailsService implements SocialUserDetailsService {
      @Autowired
      private UsuarioDao account;

      public SocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId(String userId) {
        for(Usuario usuario : account.select())
          if(usuario.getLogin().equals(userId))
            return new SocialUser(usuario.getLogin(), usuario.getSenha(), usuario.isEnabled(), usuario.isAccountNonExpired(), usuario.isCredentialsNonExpired(), usuario.isAccountNonLocked(), usuario.getAuthorities());
        return null;
      }
    }
```

**application.properties**

```
# SPRING SOCIAL (SocialWebAutoConfiguration)
spring.social.auto-connection-views=false

# SPRING SOCIAL FACEBOOK (FacebookAutoConfiguration)
spring.social.facebook.app-id=...
spring.social.facebook.app-secret=...

# SPRING SOCIAL TWITTER (TwitterAutoConfiguration)
spring.social.twitter.app-id=...
spring.social.twitter.app-secret=...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you didn't `Inject` `ConnectionSignUp` into `UsersConnectionRepository`. Therefore Spring tries redirect user to page with sign up form. To perform implicit sign up try to pass your `ConnectionSignUp` bean to `setConnectionSignUp()`.